How can i generate the arrow function format typeorm migration file?
when ever i am generating migration file i am getting this kind of format
public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> { 
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "transaction" ADD "expenseCategory" character varying(150)`);
}

public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "transaction" ADD "expenseCategory" character varying(100)`);
}

}
I want to generate arrow function format in this format
public up = async(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> => { 
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "transaction" ADD "expenseCategory" character varying(150)`);
}

public down = async(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> => {
    await queryRunner.query(`ALTER TABLE "transaction" ADD "expenseCategory" character varying(100)`);
}

}

Tangential, but why? There’s no upside, and you lose stack trace info (or at least you used to due to the anon function).
